# Which performance metric can I use for (multi) aspect based sentiment analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, python, natural-language, model-evaluation, metric

I'm working on creating a model that extracts and evaluates sentiments of aspects in the text. My problem is that I'm unsure how to evaluate my results. Currently, I'm looking at the sentiment and if the span of true text and the predicted text overlap.

**Text:** *But see the macbook pro is different because it may have a huge price tag but it comes with the full software that you would actually need and most of it has free future updates.*
**True:** ('price tag', 'negative'), ('software', 'positive'), ('updates', 'positive')
**Prediction:** ('it comes with the full software', 'positive'), ('most of it has free future updates', 'positive')

I would consider 'updates' and 'software' true predictions. 'price tag' is missing.

Do you have a hint on how I could evaluate the model?